# What are some best practices for displaying an "unsupported browser"-warning in a web app?

Tags: website-design, web-app, web, warnings

We're building a web app, and the technology we're using will only allow users with relatively modern browsers (IE8 and up, plus most versions of other browsers) to even log in. We want to show an "unsupported browser"-warning when a user tries to access the site with an older browser.

What are some best practices when designing and showing such a warning? For example, should it take over the entire page and not allow the user to take any actions at all, or should it allow the user to attempt to use the app even though a lot of things will be broken? What information should be given in the warning message, etc.?

Comment: you may have a look at that thread: http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/29324/how-to-force-users-to-upgrade-their-browser

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One of the best things to use is Google frame to avoid this kind of problems but if the user is still stuck with IE6/7 with no alternative, it should take over the entire page, take a look at basecamp and apple cloud[image: browser too old basecamp]
[image: browser too old apple]

[similar question:](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/29324/how-to-force-users-to-upgrade-their-browser)

Comment: This is great! Thanks for the answer and the link.